# Add a divider and dropdown-header to navbarMenu

Tags: r, shiny

As my shiny app grows I'm running out of space in the navbar. I would like to add a divider and dropdown-header into a navbarMenu to combine some menu items. Adding the html directly doesn't do anything. Wrapping it inside `tabPanel` does insert something but makes the dropdown-header into a link and also adds whitespace that links to ... nothing (see example code below). So not great. Is there another way to do this?

```
navbarMenu(
  tabPanel(HTML("<li class='divider'></li><li class='dropdown-header'>example header</li>")),
  tabPanel(HTML("<li class='divider'></li>"))
)
```

There seems to have been an SO question by @george-dontas about this at some point or the link inside [this page](http://www.inside-r.org/questions/adding-divider-navbarmenu-shiny) is broken.

Answer (score 0):

As @yihui [suggested](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shiny-discuss/JFCFSmAK-YQ) I filed a feature request for dividers and dropdown-headers in a navbarMenu. See [#888](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/888)